# Understanding USB in Raspberry Pi Model 4

Tags: pi-4, usb, camera, usb3

I encounter issues when reading from 2 cameras simultaneously in Raspberry Pi 4.

I connected an RGB camera to the USB3.0 port and another B/W camera to USB2.0 since cameras would be disconnected when I connected them to the same USB3.0 port.

I notice that some camera frames arrive corrupted if I run both cameras only. I thought usb2.0 and usb3.0 USB roots would be independent. Is there any way to verify if I am hitting any capacity with the USB bus, CPU-read, or any other resources?